# Adjusting the size of an array according to a variable

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

This is probably a really newbie question, but I really couldn't apply any of the other answers to my case.

Say that I have this chunk of code:

```
 int sizemes=0;

 char letrarand()
{
    int sizemes = 31;
    char mesaleat[31] = { ' ' };
    char *pMesaleat;
    pMesaleat = mesaleat;
    int  numaleat = 0, i=0;
    int randascii = 0;
    srand(time(NULL));                                                          

    for (i = 0; i < 31; i++)
        {
            numaleat= rand() % 26;
            randascii = numaleat + 65;
            *(pMesaleat+i) =randascii;
            printf("%c \t",*(pMesaleat+i));

        }
    return 0;
}
```

Where letrarand is a function that will create an array of 31 elements and assign a random capital letter to each one of those elements. Right now that works, but I want to be able to adjust the size of the array according to the variable sizeofmes, so that if that variable(which is outside of the function) is 15 the array will have 15 elements and so on. For some reason, i can't do that, any ideas?

Comment: 1. `int sizemes` is declared both out and inside the function. 2. `*(pMesaleat+i) =randascii;` where `randascii` is an `int` while `*(pMesaleat + i)` is a `char`. As an answer you shouldn't use arrays `char mesaleat[31]` but instead use [malloc](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html). e.g. `char *pMesaleat = (char*)malloc(sizeofmes * sizeof(char))`.

Comment: @CristiFati: That is nonsense! Such a small array is better automatic. OP can use a VLA to make the length variable: `char mesaleat[sizemes]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declare `sizmes` twice, which you don't want to do.  The compiler will not know which one to use.  You should also declare your pointers outside of the function if you're going to need them later.  Either way, you want to make sure you `Free` them when done to avoid memory leaks.  Declare and initialize them outside of the function, and then utilize it within, like below:

```
int sizemes = 31;
char *pMesaleat;

char letrarand()
{

    char mesaleat[sizemes] = { ' ' };

    pMesaleat = mesaleat;
    int numaleat = 0;
    int randascii = 0;
    srand(time(NULL)):                                                          

    for (int i = 0; i < sizemes; i++)
    {
        numaleat= rand() % 26;
        randascii = numaleat + 65;
        *(pMesaleat+i) = randascii;
        printf("%c \t",*(pMesaleat+i));
    }

return 0;
}

if (pMesaleat)
    Free(pMesaleat);
```

Answer (score 4):

C99 supports variable length arrays (it's optional in C11 and you can check if it's not supported using the macro `__STDC_NO_VLA__`).
So, you can do:

```
int sizemes = 31;
char mesaleat[sizemes];
```

If your implementation doesn't support VLA (or using C89) then you can resort to `malloc()`:

```
char *mesaleat = malloc(sizemes * sizeof *mesaleat);
if (!mesaleat) {
    /* error */
}
```

and so on.

Note: Call `free()` on `mesaleat` once you are done with it.

Comment: As a sidenote: Best way to deal with compilers not supporting VLAs: wipe from disc. Any modern C11 compiler also supports C99 mode and none of them does not support VLAs in C11 mode.